# Along with which clauses in MySQL 'NOT' keyword can be used? Indeed specifically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, rdbms

There is a keyword 'NOT' in **MySQL**.

For example, consider the below SQL query in **MySQL** :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country NOT LIKE '%land%';
```

See in above query 'NOT' keyword is used along with the `LIKE` keyword.

I want to know along with which clauses and keywords the `'NOT'` keyword is used specifically in MySQL database queries.

Can someone please provide me help in this regard with example queries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT` keyword can be used with any boolean expression (and hence actually with any numeric expression but let's not go there).  For example:

```
where not (a = b)
where not (a is null)
where not (a in ('x', 'y', 'z'))
where not (a = 1 or b = 2 or c = 3)
```

That is the keyword `not`.  There are at least three other infix operators that contain `not`:  `not in`, `not like`, and `is not null`.  For these, the `not` is part of the operator name, not a separate keyword.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer but you didn't get my point. I just came to know that keyword 'NOT' can be used with 'BETWEEN' operator. For example : "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Price NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20;" I'm interested to know such types of usage of 'NOT' keyword in MySQL database management system. Can you please explain me about it? Thanks once again for showing interest in helping me out. Waiting keenly for your updated answer/comment/query.

Comment: @PHPLover . . . Okay, there are at least four infix operators with `NOT` in the name, and `NOT BETWEEN` is one of them.

Comment: What are the other three?

Comment: @PHPLover . . . They are listed in the answer.